# PPCG Design Userscript

Tags: script

I've already posted this on PPCG, I'm also adding a StackApps post really as a [placeholder](/questions/tagged/placeholder) but it isn't *really* a placeholder.

---

### Screenshots

[image: Homepage]

[image: Question]

### About

StackExchange isn't graduating PPCG, so me and a few other PPCG users have taken it upon ourselves to graduate ourselves. We created own community-inspired design and also added some PPCG-specific features to it

#### Download

**[Download Link](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design/raw/master/ppcg.user.js)**

If you don't have a userscript client, you'll need one. I highly recommend [TamperMonkey](https://tampermonkey.net) (GreaseMonkey if you use firefox) is supports a *ton* of browsers. Is un-intrusive, and works pretty well.

#### Platform

All browsers are supported.

### Contact

The best way is to leave a [Github Issue](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design/issues) for feature reqs, issues, and anything related to the userscript.

This userscript was a community collaboration mainly by:

@Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ, @ETHproductions, and @ՊՓԼՃՐՊՃՈԲՍԼ

With big help from:

@PhiNotPi, @Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ, @mınxomaτ, @JAtkin, and @El'endia Starman

And additional help from:

@RikerW, @Calvin's Hobbies, and @issacg

### Code

The code is on [Github](https://github.com/vihanb/PPCG-Design). The assets are in an `svg` and all content is hosted on Github through rawgit

Comment: My name is Easterly Irk now, by the way. (used to be RikerW)